# ForEach animation with dynamically added elements buggy

Tags: swift, swiftui, uiviewcontroller, avplayer

I'm trying to mimic the TikTok style feed. This involves the following elements (Published variables are kept in an 'appState' tracking file):

First: An array that keeps track of AVPlayers to be rendered:

```
@Published var selectedPlayers: [PlayerWrapper] = []

// PlayerWrapper type looks like this

struct PlayerWrapper: Hashable {
    let item_id: Int?
    var player: AVPlayer
}
```

Second: An array that keeps track of all metadata associated with the video. This needs to be stored in a separate array for unrelated reasons.

```
@Published var selectedItems: [FeatureType] = []

// FeatureType type looks like this

struct FeatureType: Codable, Hashable {
    let item_id: Int?
    // a bunch of other properties that aren't related
}
```

I try to render the AVPlayer views in a VStack as seen below, using offsets to view the correct one in the stack:

```
struct PlayerFeed: View {
@ObservedObject var appState: AppState // contains the variables defined above
@State var relativeIndex: Int = 0
@State var viewOffset: CGSize = .zero
@State var canceledSwipe = false

var body: some View {
VStack(spacing: 0){
    ForEach(enumerating: Array(appState.selectedPlayers.enumerated()), id: \.element) { (i,player) in
        PlayerWrapperView(appState: appState, i: i)
    }
}
.offset(y: (UIScreen.main.bounds.height * CGFloat(-relativeIndex)) + viewOffset.height)
.animation({
    Animation.linear(duration: 0.25)
}())
.gesture(
    DragGesture()
        .onChanged { gesture in
            if (viewOffset.height < gesture.translation.height && viewOffset.height < -10) || (viewOffset.height > gesture.translation.height && viewOffset.height > 10) {
                canceledSwipe = true
            }
            viewOffset = gesture.translation
                    
        }
        .onEnded { _ in
            if !canceledSwipe {
                NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(object)
                appState.selectedPlayers[relativeIndex].player.seek(to: .zero)
                appState.selectedPlayers[relativeIndex].player.pause()
                        
                        
                        
                if let current_item_id = appState.selectedPlayers[relativeIndex].item_id, let current_overall_index = appState.selectedItems.firstIndex(where: { $0.item_id == current_item_id }) {
                    if viewOffset.height > 10 && current_overall_index > 0 {
                        if relativeIndex != 2 {
                            guard let item_id = appState.selectedPlayers.first?.item_id, let foundIndex = appState.selectedItems.firstIndex(where: { $0.item_id == item_id }) else { return }
                                    
                            let nextIndex = foundIndex - 1
                            if appState.selectedItems.indices.contains(nextIndex) {
                                let item = appState.selectedItems[nextIndex]
                                let player = AVPlayer(url: URL(string: item.thumbnail[0])!)
                                let wrappedPlayer = PlayerWrapper(item_id: item.item_id, player: player)
                                appState.selectedPlayers.removeLast()
                                        appState.selectedPlayers.insert(wrappedPlayer, at: 0)
                            } else {
                                relativeIndex = 0
                            }
                                    
                        } else {
                            relativeIndex -= 1
                        }
                                
                    } else if viewOffset.height < -10 && current_overall_index < appState.selectedItems.count - 1 {
                        if relativeIndex != 0 {
                            guard let item_id = appState.selectedPlayers.last?.item_id, let foundIndex = appState.selectedItems.firstIndex(where: { $0.item_id == item_id }) else { return }
                                    
                            let nextIndex = foundIndex + 1
                            if appState.selectedItems.indices.contains(nextIndex) {
                                let item = appState.selectedItems[nextIndex]
                                let player = AVPlayer(url: URL(string: item.thumbnail[0])!)
                                let wrappedPlayer = PlayerWrapper(item_id: item.item_id, player: player)
                                appState.selectedPlayers.removeFirst()
                                appState.selectedPlayers.append(wrappedPlayer)
                            } else {
                                relativeIndex = 2
                            }
                                    
                        } else {
                            relativeIndex += 1
                        }
                    }
                }
                        
                viewOffset = .zero
                        
                        
                // playing next video...
                appState.selectedPlayers[relativeIndex].player.play()
                        
                appState.selectedPlayers[relativeIndex].player.actionAtItemEnd = .none
                        
                object = NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: appState.selectedPlayers[relativeIndex].player.currentItem, queue: .main) { (_) in
                    print(NotificationCenter.default.debugDescription)
                    let playerItem = appState.selectedPlayers[relativeIndex].player
                    playerItem.seek(to: .zero)
                    playerItem.play()
                }
            } else {
                viewOffset = .zero
                canceledSwipe = false
            }
        }
)
.onAppear {
            
    // doing it for first video because scrollview didnt dragged yet...
            
    appState.selectedPlayers[0].player.play()
            
    appState.selectedPlayers[0].player.actionAtItemEnd = .none
            
    object = NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: appState.selectedPlayers[0].player.currentItem, queue: .main) { (_) in
                
        // notification to identify at the end of the video...
        let playerItem = appState.selectedPlayers[0].player
        playerItem.seek(to: .zero)
        playerItem.play()
                
    }
}
.frame(height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height, alignment: .top)
.background(Color.black.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all))
}
}
```

For simplicity purposes, PlayerWrapperView just contains a line of code 'Player' that is a UIViewControllerRepresentable and can run the AVPlayer.

```
Player(appState: appState, player: $appState.selectedPlayers[i].player) // the player I want to run
```

I am dynamically adding/removing players from the selectedPlayers array because when they are all rendered, the phone can't handle it (besides, I think there is a hard limit of 16 on AVPlayers that can be rendered). The AVPlayer url it pulls from comes out of the selectedItems array (an equivalent array index-wise). For some reason, when I swipe between videos in the Feed, I get a kind of glitchy behavior (not a smooth animation). In addition, sometimes the AVPlayer will render black, audio will cut out, etc. Not sure how to fix these issues. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Don't ignore the compiler warnings. `animation(_:)` was deprecated in iOS 15 for a good reason. It does not work properly. Use `withAnimation(_:_:)` or `animation(_:value:)` instead.

Comment: @Yrb In this case I'm assuming I should wrap the if let current_item_id block in withAnimation or replace my .animation modifier with .animation(Animation.linear(duration: 0.25), value: selectedPlayers). Neither of these solutions worked unfortunately as both still exhibit broken/laggy animation.

Comment: This needs a [Minimal Reproducible Example (MRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). There is no way to figure out the problem without being able to properly test it. We can't even tell if you used them properly, as we can't see or run the code. Also, often times making an MRE solves the problem for you.